# Can you create a cell shade effect using normal maps?

Tags: normal-map, toon-shading

I've seen this image before and it's made me curious to see if it's possible to use normal maps to create cell shading. Am I on the right track here or is this image showing something else.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This question is broader than you might think :) Normals (and edited normals) _are_ used  all over the place in NPR, for all kinds of reasons, Make, e.g., a first-shot search on 'Blender NPR Normal'. You are on the right track, but this Q might be too broad for a nice neat BSE answer.

Answer (score 4):

One popular realistic part of NPR is simulating light. A surface typically becomes brighter as it gets more perpendicular to the light rays, because it means more light rays hit the same surface:

[image]

A 2D artist has to imagine the angle of a surface towards lightning and draw it brighter/darker depending on that angle. If you wanted to automate that process, you would need to somehow obtain that angle info, which is exactly what normal data is, except it doesn't tell you the angle to the light, just the angle (defined by a point 1 m away, by describing how far this point is on X, Y, Z axes, e.g. X:-0.866m, Y:+0.5m, Z:0).

Using an arbitrary angle of an imaginary light, we can calculate the angle toward that light and base the shading on that:

[image]

Normalize is there just so it's easier to edit the input Vector defining the angle of the light. Without normalizing, you would have to make sure the defined point is 1 m away; that is, you could not care about it, but then changing the position of light would affect the average distance from the light, yielding inconsistent overall brightness depending on the light setting.

Some additional math (or color ramp) is needed to black more than just the surfaces facing the opposite direction than the light (you want a face being parallel to a light ray to already be black).

Snapping is used to simulate a limited number of colors an artist uses.

And as you can see, unlike in 2D art, this algorithm doesn't consider occlusion:

[image]

This is why typical NPR shaders take advantage of Shader-to-RGB node to first generate a realistic color, and based on that produce NPR color.